# Does a SendMessage() call from another thread posts a message to the message queue?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have read two contradictory concepts about calling `SendMessage()` from another thread:

- The first is that a message will be posted to the message queue.
- The second is that `SendMessage()` will be called directly. However, the calling thread will block, and the context is switched to the UI thread, and then the window procedure is called, and when it returns, the calling thread is unblocked and the context is switched back to it.

So which one is correct?

Comment: SendMessage() never posts to the message queue.  *Some* of them will be automatically marshaled from the calling thread to the thread that owns the window.  But that can only work for system messages, the kind that Windows itself knows about.  Not something to ever rely on.

Comment: The link in SendMessage about [nonqueued messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#nonqueued_messages) may help clarify this a bit.  Basically, the message is sent to the target thread in some unspecified way, probably actually via a queue of *some* kind - but it bypasses the conventional thread message queue, the one the programmer can manipulate directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) is, in my view, reasonably clear:

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.

Messages sent with `SendMessage` are never placed on the message queue. In other words, your first bullet point is completely false.

In the case where a message is sent cross-thread, it is dispatched in the thread that owns the window, typically by calls to `GetMessage` in the recipient thread's message loop. There are other functions, e.g. `PeekMessage`, `SendMessage` etc., that will dispatch messages.

Comment: "Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code" Why am I supposed to retrieve a message if no message is posted?!

Comment: The typical message loop has a call to `GetMessage`. That call will block if there is nothing in the queue. When another thread sends a message to the thread that is blocking in `GetMessage`, the recipient thread wakes up, dispatches the sent message, and then resumes its wait for a queued message.

Comment: @EJP The recipient thread is signaled that a synchronous message is waiting.

Comment: @joseph_m because of typical MS waffle.  Instead of describing EXACTLY what is going on, they wrap up the exact mechanism in wool.  Since many threads my attempt a SendMessage() call 'at the same time', then a queueing mechanism is required.  The important thing is that the thread that issues the SendMessage is blocked until the message is handled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't find that any clearer than 'switches to that thread'. Signalled how?

Comment: Probably a queued 'APC' call?

Comment: @EJP Why does that matter? All you need to know is that the window procedure is executed in the thread that owns the window

Comment: It matters because it isn't clear how it could possibly work as described. It's been puzzling me for decades. What mechanism is involved? Is there some piece of secret synchronization somehow via `GetMessage()`? Implying that if the target thread isn't *in* `GeMessage()` the source thread has to wait? Like @MartinJames I find the language here pretty woolly.

Comment: @EJP Well, the sender will have to wait until the recipient thread calls one of the message retrieval functions. I cannot see how this could be done with an APC because the messages are only dispatched from specific functions: `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`, `SendMessage`, and a handful of other functions. I haven't got the full list to hand.

Comment: I'm sure that one of the good books on Windows internals would clear this all up, but I sometimes feel that the authors of some MSDN pages, (especially those on inter-thread comms stuff like these message calls), were on Tequila at the time they wrote them.

Comment: @MartinJames Or at least that they weren't adequately briefed. I've never found this area of Windows comprehensible or properly documented, and I started programming it in 1990.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess you could call it a kind of coroutining between `SendMessage()` and the message retrieval functions concerned.

Comment: @Martin: The MSDN describes the **contract**, not the **implementation**. In terms of the contract, what information do you find lacking?

Comment: @IInspectable What *I* have found lacking for 25 years is the slightest piece of plausible language that suggests it actually works that way it is described, and it is clear from David's comments that it actually doesn't. They're prepared to be as specific as 'as a subroutine', which is implementation, not contract, but 'switches to that thread' is just waflfle, as Martin said.

Comment: @IInspectable nothing,.  The issue is the FUD that arises from the loose implementation implications.  For example, 'the system switches to that thread' strongly implies that the switch is a proactive action of the SendMessage call, (which it is not, since the target thread must be in a position to respond to whatever signaling is used).

Comment: @Martin: *"The system is instructed to put the target thread into an alertable state, upon which, at some point in the future, if system resources allow, the target thread - upon entering a message retrieval function - is allowed to continue executing, servicing the request to dispatch the message."* Personally, I find *"the system switches to that thread"* a lot more comprehensible. Again, please do explain which information is missing, that prevents you from writing an application against a contract, that behaves exactly as described?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't find either of them comprehensible. The existence of this question is a sufficient rebuttal, but in any case it's a straw man argument, unless your quote is also official Microsoft documentation, which you haven't stated. It is also frankly just more waffle.

Comment: @EJP: If you started Windows programming in 1990, then all of this should be **crystal clear** to you. After all, you understand coöperative multitasking, and are intimately familiar with the invariants, that had to survive the switch to preemptive multitasking.

Comment: @IInspectable: as currently written, the first sentence implies that the window's message procedure will be called preemptively, regardless of what the target thread is currently doing.  If that were true, it would have all sorts of nasty implications.  The second sentence attempts to clarify that it *isn't* true, but does not do so convincingly, hence questions like this one.  Both sentences could be replaced by something like "If the specified window was created by a different thread, the appropriate window procedure will be called the next time that thread executes message retrieval code."